# Can I fork processes and exec internal functions?

Tags: c, fork, exec

I've really searched for this and all I can find is that you can execvp() shell commands.

I'm wondering if I can fork processes and then have them run a function that's internal to the program? (As in, a function I've written myself within the code)

Comment: If the function is in the same executable, then there should be nothing stopping you from invoking it just as you would from the original process. Post the code you've tried, and perhaps explain the problem in more detail (at least the first, preferably *both*).

Comment: The issue was with his ambiguous wording on this assignment. He asked us to write a function, fork processes, and then exec our function in parallel. I think he was using exec as shorthand for execute, and he didn't mean use exec(). I tend to over complicate problems too.... Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can have the child execute one function and the parent execute a different (or even the same) function in the same executable.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
    err_syserr("failed to fork: ");
else if (pid == 0)
    be_childish();
else
    be_parental();
```

You can add arguments to `be_childish()` and `be_parental()` as needed.  Before the code executes `fork()`, you can create pipes or sockets to communicate between them — or semaphores, and shared memory, or whatever IPC you want.

Comment: !he wording on the assignment was funky. This is what I'm going to use. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

When you call fork, a new process is created inheriting the current context of the parent process. The child and parent processes can execute independently calling any function within your program. However, if they need to communicate/synchronize with each other, they need to use one of the IPC mechanisms such as shared memories, pipes, semaphores etc.

Comment: On this assignment they don't need IPC. I'm just gonna call the functions

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the simplest answer here is an example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int child_foo(void)
{
    /* This child process just counts to three. */

    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        printf("Foo: %d\n", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }

    printf("Foo is done.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static int child_bar(unsigned long  n)
{
    /* This child process checks if n is prime or not. */ 
    const unsigned long  imax = (n + 1) / 2;
    unsigned long        i;

    for (i = 2; i <= imax; i++)
        if (!(n % i)) {
            printf("Bar: Because %lu is divisible by %lu, %lu is not a prime.\n", n, i, n);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    printf("Bar: %lu is prime.\n", n);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t  p, foo, bar;
    int    status;

    printf("Forking child processes.\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    foo = fork();
    if (foo == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else
    if (!foo)
        return child_foo();

    bar = fork();
    if (bar == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        /* Wait until all child processes (here, foo only) have completed. */
        do {
            p = wait(NULL);
        } while (p != -1 || errno == EINTR);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else
    if (!bar)
        return child_bar(227869319);

    /* Wait until all child processes have completed. */
    do {
        p = wait(&status);
        if (p == foo || p == bar) {
            /* Report exit status. */
            if (p == foo)
                printf("child_foo()");
            else
                printf("child_bar()");
            if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == EXIT_SUCCESS)
                    printf(" exited successfully (EXIT_SUCCESS).\n");
                else
                if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == EXIT_FAILURE)
                    printf(" exited with failure (EXIT_FAILURE).\n");
                else
                    printf(" exited with status %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            } else
            if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
                printf(" died from signal %d (%s).\n", WTERMSIG(status), strsignal(WTERMSIG(status)));
            else
                printf(" was lost.\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    } while (p != -1 || errno == EINTR);

    printf("All done.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Above, `main()` forks two child processes. One of them runs `child_foo()` and exits, the other runs `child_bar(227869319)` and exits. The parent process reaps all child processes, and returns the cause of exit and exit status if available, then exits itself as well.

The `fflush(stdout)` before the `fork()` is there to remind that internal caches (including caching done by the C library) should be flushed before forking, or else the child process will inherit the cache contents. In the case of `stdout`, this would mean duplicated outputs.

In practice, it is often better for maintainability (human programmer understanding) to "return" from the child process functions using `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`, than `return`. Then, in `main()`, instead of say `return child_foo()`, you'd have say

```
        child_foo(); /* Never returns. */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

where the `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` is just a bug catcher, in case a modification to `child_foo()` causes it to return rather than exit.

In some cases the return pattern is useful, if there is cleanup work that must always be done before the child process exits. In that case, you usually put that cleanup work in a separate function, and then replace `return child_foo()` with

```
        int  exitstatus;

        exitstatus = child_foo();
        cleanup_function();
        exit(exitstatus);
```

Note that in `main()`, `return exitstatus;` and `exit(exitstatus);` are exactly equivalent (C89 2.1.2.2, C99 5.1.2.2.3p1, C11 5.1.2.2.3p1). The only difference is to us humans; it *may* be easier for us humans to correctly interpret the intent behind `exit(exitstatus)` in the middle of `main()`, compared to `return exitstatus;`. Myself, I "parse" them the same, but I seem to use `return` more.

The [`strsignal()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsignal.3.html) function is defined in POSIX-1.2008, and is only called if you manage to kill one of the child processes with an external signal without killing the parent as well. If your C library does not support it, just remove it (also remove the `%s` printf specifier, too).

As usual, the second most important thing to do, is to ensure future developers understand the intent correctly.  I included pretty minimal comments, but both the function names and the initial comment in the child process functions should make the intent clear.  I'm sure you can do even better. (I do consider commenting to be the hardest part in programming for me. It is so easy to write useless comments that describe what the code does, but omit the *intent*.  When you look at even your own code months later, you forget your thoughts then, and must rely on the comments (and indirectly infer from the code) to get a proper understanding of the intent.  Good comments are hard to write!)

In my opinion, the most important thing is to ensure the program is robust, and does not silently corrupt data. This means sufficient error checking (in my case, paranoid -- I *really* don't want to silently corrupt data) and minimal assumptions on what "ought to" succeed.  Sometimes, it leads to "nests" of code, like the `status` checks in the `wait()` loop in `main()`. I deliberately left out the comments there, because I believe you should go through it, keeping a browser or terminal window open to [`man 2 wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html), and add the necessary comments so you understand exactly what that nest of code does. It will definitely help you understand a lot about how processes can terminate or be terminated, and how a parent process can detect that.

Comment: This was also beyond the scope of my question but taught me more about processes. We really do just skim things in school it seems. We're mostly just worried about zombies and orphans for class, but data corruption, caching; all important too. Thanks for this answer

Answer (score 1):

You `fork` a [*process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (a *running*, active, instance of a program) and you `execve` an [*executable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (a passive file, usually in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format) - not some functions. Read again [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html). See also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand better the role of an OS.

> that you can execvp() shell commands.

**Wrong.** `execvp` calls `execve` and runs executables (not shell commands; e.g. you cannot `execvp` the `cd` shell builtin). It does not use the shell (but `execvp` search your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) as your shell does).

Notice that every process has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). And `fork` creates a *new* process with its own new virtual address space (which happens to be a copy of the virtual address space of the parent. That copy happens lazily, read about [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) techniques). `execve` is *replacing* the virtual address process by a new one (described in the executable file).

Since that new virtual address space (after a successful `fork`, in the child process) is a copy of the parent one, it also contains the code of every internal function you dream of from your program. So after a `fork` you can call these internal functions.

Use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to understand the virtual address space of processes. At first, run `cat /proc/$$/maps` then `pmap $$` in a terminal, and try to understand its output (it describes the virtual address space of your shell process).

When a process is running, you could extend its virtual address space using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). This is used by `malloc`, and also by [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (which enables you to load [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) into your process).

PS. I am guessing you are using Linux.

Comment: This was beyond the scope of my questions. However, this has increased my knowledge of processes. I really appreciate that. In my senior year at school and I'm starting to realize that I know a LITTLE bit about a lot of things, but I want to delve deeper now. And you're right, executables, not shell commands. I need to work on my terminology too. Lastly, yes; for our systems/OS classes we use Linux and C.